# Iterate over Array of Objects in Java and extract the key and value

Tags: java, arraylist, dictionary

I am receiving the data as an Array of Object which I am accepting as `List<Object> data = new ArrayList<Object>();` and then need to iterate over to get the key value pair from object. Example :

```
Data send from JavaScript :

data : {[
     {
        name : abc,
        key : [
            {
              name : 1,
              value : 2
            },
            {
              name : 3,
              set : 4
            }
        ] 
     },
     {
        name : def,
        key : [
            {
              name : 5,
              value : 2
            },
            {
              name : 9,
              set : 7
            }
        ]
      }
]}
```

Extraction of first Object from the ArrayList gives the below result :

```
{name=abc, key=[{name=1, value=2}, {name=3, set=4}]}
```

Now, I need to get the key "name" and its value "abc" as String. And for the key "key" I need to access individual Object and extract the key, i.e., "name", and its value i.e., "1" as String. I am not able to understand how to iterate over the above List and extract the key and value as String. Please help.

Comment: Are you sure you have `name=abc` and not `name: abc`?

Comment: Yes. Till this point I have no problem. But after that I am not able to iterate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I strongly encourage you to use a JSON library, such as [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/), when dealing with JSON input, but:

Since you write that you're working with

```
{name=abc, key=[{name=1, value=2}, {name=3, set=4}]}
```

and you say that you have an `ArrayList<Object>` I'm going to make an educated guess and say that your ArrayList contains a `Map` with `name` and `key` as keys. (And that you *printed* this map with `System.out.println`.

Now if you have a map it's quite simple:

```
Map<String, Object> map = (Map<String, Object>) myList.get(0);
for (String key : map.keySet())
    System.out.println("Key: " + key + " maps to value: " + map.get(key));
```

Comment: It would be great if you can help me iterate over the list `{name=abc, key=[{name=1, value=2}, {name=3, set=4}]}`.

Comment: Are you certain you have `=` and not `:`? And are you certain that you have `name=abc` and not `name="abc"`? (because that's not valid JSON which means that you would have to write a parser from scratch)

Comment: Yes I am very sure because I am converting it to `List`. Its `name=abc` and not `name="abc"`

Comment: Ok. Updated my answer with an educated guess of where you're at.

Comment: Yes you are right. I have a `Map` with `name` and `key` as keys. Now what I need to do to iterate over `[{name=1, value=2}, {name=3, set=4}]` to extract the `key` and `value`.

Comment: Check out the code snippet at the bottom of my answer.

Comment: Yes I am able to get it to iterate over `[{name=1, value=2}, {name=3, set=4}]` now. Thanks for the help.